# Capturing entire repeated string based on a repeated pattern

Tags: python, regex

Following regex matches both `59-59-59` and `59-59-59-59` and outputs only `59`
The intent is to match four and only numbers followed by `-` with the max number being `59`. Numbers less than `10` are represented as `00-09`.

```
print(re.match(r'(\b[0-5][0-9]-{1,4}\b)','59-59-59').groups())
--> output ('59-',)
```

I need a pattern match that matches exactly `59-59-59-59`

and does not match `59--59-59`or `59-59-59-59-59`

Comment: [`^[0-5][0-9](?:-[0-5][0-9]){3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/SKtRbA/2)

Comment: If all you need is validate a whole string of 4 `-`-separated numbers, use `re.match(r'[0-5][0-9](?:-[0-5][0-9]){3}$', s)`. If there can be 1 to 4 of the numbers replace `{3}` with `{0,3}`. If you need to get the numbers after validation, use `s.split('-')` after the string validation passes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following pattern, if using `re.match`:

```
[0-5][0-9](?:-[0-5][0-9]){3}$
```

This is phrased to match an initial number starting with 0 through 5, followed by any second digit.  Then, this is followed by a dash and a number with the same rules, this quantity three times exactly.  Note that `re.match` anchor at the beginning by default, so we only need an ending anchor `$`.

Code:

```
print(re.match(r'([0-5][0-9](?:-[0-5][0-9]){3})$', '59-59-59-59').groups())

('59-59-59-59',)
```

If you intend to actually match the *same* number four times in a row, then see the answer by @Thefourthbird.

If you want to find such a string in a larger text, then consider using `re.search`.  In that case, use this pattern:

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))[0-5][0-9](?:-[0-5][0-9]){3}(?=\s|$)
```

Note that instead of using word boundaries `\b` I used lookarounds to enforce the end of the "word" here.  This means that the above pattern will *not* match something like `59-59-59-59-59`.

Comment: This will also match `59-59-59-59` in the string `59-59-59-59-59`

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Why does `print(re.match(r'(\b(?:-[0-5][0-9]){4}\b)', '59-59-59-57').groups())` not work?

Comment: @barry_allen You require 4 hyphens in the match, and your string has only 3. You also require the match to be at the start of the string and there is no hyphen there

Comment: @Potato Thanks for pointing this out and I have fixed it.  My brain is now fried like a French fry!

Answer (score 3):

In your pattern, this part `-{1,4}` matches 1-4 times a hyphen so `59--` will match.

If all the matches should be the same as 59, you could use a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to the first capturing group and repeat that 3 times with a prepended hyphen.

```
\b([0-5][0-9])(?:-\1){3}\b
```

Your code might look like:

```
import re
res = re.match(r'\b([0-5][0-9])(?:-\1){3}\b', '59-59-59-59')
if res:
    print(res.group())
```

If there should not be partial matches, you could use an anchors to assert the `^` start and the end `$` of the string:

```
^([0-5][0-9])(?:-\1){3}$
```

Comment: Not sure the OP wants this (the question is unclear), but this is a good answer nonetheless.

Comment: This will also match `59-59-59-59` in the string `59-59-59-59-59`

Comment: @Potato The is why I added `If there should not be partial matches, you could use an anchors to assert the ^ start and the end $ of the string.`

Comment: `print(re.match(r'(\b([0-5][0-9])(?:-\1){3}\b)', '59-59-59-59').groups())` fails -> `raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: cannot refer to open group`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Apologies. I missed that part.

Comment: @barry_allen Try it like this without the outer capturing group `print(re.match(r'\b([0-5][0-9])(?:-\1){3}\b', '59-59-59-59').group())`

Comment: @Potato No problem at all.